# Event handling on Manager in BlackBerry

Tags: events, blackberry, user-interface, java-me

I had added one [VerticalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/VerticalFieldManager.html) on a [Screen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html). I want to handle event on that manager in such a way that it should set particular variable value with respect to that manager preferred height. Following is my code snippet, please check it.

```java
VerticalFieldManager leftVfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        super.sublayout(screenWidth - 150, INFO_HEADER_HEIGHT);
        setExtent(screenWidth - 150, INFO_HEADER_HEIGHT);
    }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        int eventCode = message.getEvent();
        if (eventCode == TouchEvent.DOWN) {
            // leftheight should be leftVfm.getPreferredHeight();
            INFO_HEADER_HEIGHT = leftheight;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there any solution? Please help me.

Comment: Your goal is not clear here.  You want to change the layout height of the VFM when the user is tapping on it?  Can you give us some more context about the goal?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue : Yes you are going in right way.I want to change height of VFM when user tap on it.

Comment: I am facing same problem like Dany is there any solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

The comment in your code says:

`// leftheight should be leftVfm.getPreferredHeight();`

Since you want to alter the height, using a variable name like INFO_HEADER_HEIGHT is a bit misleading, as an all caps name indicates a constant i.e. `static final` which means the value won't be changing.

Once you change your height variable, you just need to force the manager to layout again.  The most direct way of doing that is calling Screen.invalidateLayout()

Comment: Can you tell me how should i retrieve height of that leftvfm after tapping  event on it